# How do I use an Entity Framework 4 model without a real database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I don't need any data to be stored. I'd like an application to start, create an Entity Framework entities container based on the model I've designed but having no data records in it, then generate some data (from user input and other input sources), work with it and discard all the data on close, without propagating any data operations made with EF contect to a real database hosted on server or in a file. How do I implement such a pattern?

I want this because I want my non-persistent objects to expose "LINQ to Entities" functionality for manipulating and binding to WF and WPF controls.

I use Entity Framework 4 and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: If you don't have a database, why the trouble setting up a Entity Framework model at all? Why don't you just have List<T> and graphs of objects, and use Linq-to-Objects on those in-memory structures?

Comment: But I believe EF4 must have some internal concept of rolling back transactions (so that it doesn't have to trash any cached data after a rollback) - EF4 without a database could provide that in a way that Linq-to-objects cannot, right?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use EF for "LINQ to Entities" you can use "LINQ to Objects" on simple POCOs by exposing your collections as IEnumerable.

Here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx